# Change underline color Material Ui SCSS

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui

in my current project I encountered the problem that I need to change the color of the underline with SCSS, before I did this using the palette in themes.
For now I got a line to display using the following code.

```
.input {
   border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

But this is obvisously only a workarround. has anyone any idea how to disable the underline (the snippets utilizing the input props didn't work for me) or changing the color palette?

Edit: 
I found a solution. I just added

```
div::after{
   border-bottom: 2px solid red !important;
}
div::before{
   border-bottom: 1px solid grey !important;
}
```

to the code and now it works :D

Kind regards,
Frodo

Comment: Try: `text-decoration-color: red; // for color example`

Comment: By disabling an underline i think you mean getting rid of it and for that the css is `text-decoration: none !important;` added to your .input rule.

Comment: Sadly both don't work :/ The line is still blue and there.